# Replace Complex Head with List

Tags: replacement, complex, head

I would like to apply `ListPlot` to a set of complex numbers. This is what comes to mind to convert a complex number to a pair:
`Replace[5 + 2 I, {Complex -> List}, Heads -> True]`
except it doesn't work. Neither do the other solutions to similar questions I've seen on this site.

I can get around it by defining `f[x_]:={Re[x],Im[x]}` but I'm curious why the replacement does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Complex` is an *atomic* type.

```
AtomQ@Complex[1, 2]
(* True *)
```

In other words, it is a smallest unit that should be considered [indivisible](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=atom&allowed_in_frame=0).

For atomic types, you cannot assume any structure.  Somewhat confusingly, *some* of them behave as if they did have a structure in *some* situations.  But this is by no means general.

Notice that this works:

```
Replace[Complex[1, 2], Complex[a_, b_] :> {a, b}]
(* {1, 2} *)
```

Even this works:

```
Replace[Complex[1, 2], head_[a_, b_] -> {head, a, b}]
(* {Complex, 1, 2} *)
```

So, of course, it is natural to expect this to work too:

```
Replace[Complex[1, 2], Complex -> List, {1}, Heads -> True]
```

(Notice that you would need the `{1}`. This was a mistake in your code, but it's really beside the main point here.)

However, this returns `Complex[1,2]` back.

This is what I meant when I said *some* atomic expressions behave *as if* they had a structure *sometimes*, but not always.  For atoms, all bets are off when trying to decompose them.  I suggest you stick to `Re` and `Im`, or more conveniently, `ReIm`.

If you try to decompose other atomic types, you will see different behaviour.  Each one has its own quirks.

Comment: nice answer: +1. was just about to post the solution. Your explanation is very enlightening !

Answer (score -1):

In:

```
cs = Table[5 + 2 I, 3];

(*Method 1*)
cs // Map[ReIm]

(*Method 2*)
reim[c_] := ReIm[c]
SetAttributes[reim, Listable];
reim @ cs 

(*Method 3*)
cs // FullForm // ToString // 
  StringReplace[#, "Complex" -> "List"] & // ToExpression
```

Out:

```
{{5, 2}, {5, 2}, {5, 2}}
{{5, 2}, {5, 2}, {5, 2}}
{{5, 2}, {5, 2}, {5, 2}}
```

Comment: Don't even have to set ReIm to Listable In[232]:= ReIm // Attributes Out[232]= {Listable, Protected}